# Resurfacing Mesh After Spin Operation

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

I'm using Blender to create models for 3D printing.  Right now I'm using the spin tool to revolve a basic 3D shape around a center axis so that it create a set of overlapping identical units.  Think 24 cubes spun around the z-axis to create a ring of overlapping cubes.

This creates 24 overlapping cubes that intersect one another as a single object.  What I need is to remove the intersected areas and create a mesh that is just the surface of this new shape, rather than multiple intersected units.

So far I have tried using the Remesh modifier on the object, but it has not proved helpful.  I'm not sure if this is the correct tool for this purpose or if I am even using it correctly.

What would be the correct way (or at least "a correct way") to do this and achieve the result I am looking for? (Exterior unified mesh with no overlapping internals).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a sort of "donut" shape with sharp edges?

Comment: To be honest, such workflow should better be avoided, I mean the probability in creating intersection parts that you have to remove then. Or at least you can upload a screenshot to show what you are going to do exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you got something like that by [spinning](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Duplicating/Spin) a cube (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>):

[image]

You could simply use a plane for spinning to avoid the issues:

[image]

Note: Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to remove duplicates and spin operator was invoked  in *Edit Mode* (*Top Ortho View*)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Boolean Modifier, which will fuse two meshes when using the "Union" operation.
But if you want to have a perfectly clean mesh, I'd rather advise you to use the Array Modifier to scatter your object around an Empty and edit the object itself to finally achieve your ring.